# How to sort has_many :through in an edit form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, sorting, has-many-through

Given the following Model, Relationship & Edit Form

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed
  has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id",
                               class_name: "Relationship",
                               dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower

end
```

---

```
<%= form_for(@topic) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.label :Followers %>
    <%= f.fields_for :relationships do |builder| %>
        <%= f.collection_select :follower_id, User.all( order: "name"), :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
    <% end %>


    <%= f.submit "Save Changes" %></div>
<% end %>
```

---

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :followed_id

  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"

  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

---

In this case, the fields for relationships appear in the edit form for a given user. Thus, they can manage all of their followers. But the problem is, on the edit page, the users show up in the order they were added. Is there any way to sort them such that they appear alphabetically by name, despite the fact that the :relationships association has only an id?